# Extern variables in C

Tags: c

I'm having significant trouble getting program-wide global variables and functions to work. I've tried defining my functions/variables in .c files, then declaring them (with the extern keyword in the case of variables) in headers, but both VC and GCC give me unresolved symbol/undefined reference errors. For example:

glob.c

```
#include "glob.h"

int i = 5;

char get_letter()
{
    return 'A';
}
```

glob.h

```
#ifndef GLOB_H
#define GLOB_H

extern int i;

char get_letter();

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "glob.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%u\t%c\n", i, get_letter());
}
```

This feels redundant to ask, but it looks to me like I've tried the solutions presented in existing resources and am still getting errors. How should I, once and for all, define global variables in C?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: You'd need to compile both main.c and glob.c, then link them together. If you compile only main into an executable, it won't have a source for that `i` var, because you never linked it against glob.o

Answer (score 9):

You're probably compiling it wrong, since it looks ok. When compiling multiple sources you need to do

```
gcc main.c glob.c -o program
```

Or compile separately and then link

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c glob.c
gcc main.o glob.o -o program
```